# Swift: call methods of an optional variable

Tags: swift, optional-operator

So I know the difference between '!' and '?', I just want to know what is the best way to use them when calling a method of an optional variable

```
var bar: Bar? = nil

bar?.doSomething()  // this will be valid, but wouldn't call doSomething
bar!.doSomething() // Given error: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONS (Obviously)
```

But when 'bar' is not nil, these two method-calls are both valid.

```
bar = Bar()
bar?.doSomething()  // Valid
bar!.doSomething()  // Valid
```

So my question is, what is the best way to call methods of an optional variable, I personally use:

```
if bar != nil {
    bar!.doSomething()
}
```

or will **bar?.doSomething()** do exactly the same?

Comment: Rule of thumb: each time you can avoid writing a `!`, do so (except for negating a `Bool`). This includes e.g. the forced downcast `as!`. `!` means `Hey! Don't do it! It's dangerous! I warned you!`

Comment: `!` means `I know exactly what I am doing! I am the developer and I decide how my program should run! It's not up to some variable to decide if a method should be called!`. In my opinion Objective-C developers tend to overuse `?`. If you optional chain things together that shouldn't be optional (from a software design point of view) you are emulating the friendly nil from Objective-C.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch `!` means `I am the developer and I never make mistakes! My program always runs exactly as! I decided!`
In my opinion `!` means simply `this should never be nil, do not continue if it does.`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think it is bad advice to avoid `bar?.doSomething()` and always use `if let bar = bar { ... }` instead.

There are two main reasons:

First, `bar?.doSomething()` simply is more concise. If you are writing an `if let` with just one statement in the conditional expression then you should probably ask yourself if you don't want to put that code on a single line with the shorter version.

Although this is perfectly legal code ..

```
if let thing = thing {
    thing.bar()
}
```

.. the following is just as legal, just a lot shorter ..

```
thing?.bar()
```

Second, more important and to the core of this issue, they are not the same! The `if let` is a combined test, optional unwrapping and assignment while `bar?` does something called *Optional Chaining*.

The latter is super useful in a number of cases that lets you write much nicer code. For example:

It can be used to replace this ..

```
var imageGenerator: ImageGenerator?

if let generator = imageGenerator {
    myView.image = generator.generateImage()
} else {
    myView.image = nil
}
```

.. simply with:

```
myView.image = self.imageGenerator?.generateImage()
```

The reason for this is because the *Optional Chaining* returns `nil` as soon as it encounters `nil` in the *chain*. And since `UIImageView` has an `image: UIImage?`, it takes that nil value. Even if it comes from a `ImageGenerator?`

It is even more useful when combined with the *Nil Coalescing Operator*, `??`.

Now you can turn this code ..

```
var imageGenerator: ImageGenerator?

if let generator = imageGenerator {
    myView.image = generator.generateImage()
} else {
    myView.image = DefaultImage
}
```

.. into ..

```
myView.image = generator?.makeImageGenerator() ?? DefaultImage
```

.. which is way more concise.

And because *Optional Chaining* works on *Chains* .. you can even do something like:

```
myView.image = delegate?.makeImageGenerator()?.generateImage() ?? DefaultImage
```

Which would become ..

```
if let delegate = delegate {
    if let generator = delegate.generatorForImage() {
        if let image = generator.generateImage() {
            myView.image = image
        } else {
            myView.image = DefaultImage
        }
    } else {
        myView.image = DefaultImage
    }
} else {
    myView.image = DefaultImage
}
```

.. if you did not use the *Optional Chaining* and the *Nil Coalescing Operator*.

(Yes the `myView.image = DefaultImage` could be done only conditionally at the end, but that means you still have to introduce additional code to check if it was set. It wont be much shorter.)

There, two new tricks :-)

Answer (score 5):

When you do

```
bar?.doSomething()
```

it is called Optional Chaining: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

That means, in case bar is nil, it won't continue to doSomething method, but return a nil. If you want to handle cases where it is nil, you should check if an object contains nil or not. You could also do it like this, by optional binding:

```
if let unwrappedBar = bar {
    unwrappedBar.doSomething()
} else {
    doSomeOtherThing() // In case it's nil
}
```

It makes the value available inside the if let statement as a temporary constant called unwrappedBar (you can give it any other name if you want), if it isn't nil.

You can also use a shorter syntax with optional chaining and coalescing operator:

```
bar?.doSomething() ?? doSomeOtherThing()
```

Here's more info about different ways to access optional values: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330

Comment: Great, I should use **if let** more often

Comment: That is not a closure actually.

Answer (score 2):

```
bar?.doSomething()
```

is the best way to call a method of an optional variable. It only calls do something if bar is not nil. You write the least code and it is exactly like implementing an `if let` check

```
if let bar = bar {
    bar.doSomething()
}
```

Comment: I think this is better advice than 'always use `if let`'. This form exists for a reason: it is concise. The `if let` is still useful but not for single method calls in my opinion - if you use `bar` more than once, then `if let` is probably better.